# Trying to build Qt 6.3.1 and dynamic linked with OpenSSL 3.0.5 on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, build, qt6

I am trying to build Qt 6.3.1 and dynamically linked with OpenSSL 3x on Windows.
In the past, I can build Qt 6.1.3 with OpenSSL 3x and there is no problem at all. But with Qt 6.3.1 I think the default option for SSL functions is built with `schannel`
Please ref this link: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-82876

I've try to disable this option (`schannel`) in the file: `qtbase/cmake/configure-cmake-mapping.md`:

[image]

And here are my config options (add `-no-schannel` which I've added as above):

> configure.bat -D FD_SETSIZE=4096 -release -prefix %DESTINATIONDIR%
> -shared -platform win32-msvc -opensource -confirm-license -openssl-linked -no-schannel -sql-psql -sql-sqlite -qt-zlib -qt-pcre --system-proxies -no-gui -no-widgets -no-gif -no-libpng -no-libjpeg -no-freetype -no-harfbuzz -no-accessibility -no-icu -no-fontconfig -no-opengl -no-egl -no-evdev -no-mtdev -no-sql-odbc -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests  -- -D OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=%DEPENDENCIES_DIR%\openssl

And in the summary options, it also logs that `schannel` is disabled:

[image]

But when I check the module `Qt6Network.dll` it is not linked to `OpenSSL` libs

[image]

**My expected is**: the dependencies of `Qt6Network.dll` is linked to OpenSSL libs

[image]

**So my questions are:**

1. How can I turn off `schannel` in the correct way?
2. How can I make `Qt6Network` dynamically linked to OpenSSL libs?

Appreciate any help here, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've found that with Qt 6.2 and above, SSL function lib is not directly linked with the Qt6Network module anymore, it links through the plugin called `tls`

[image]
[image]

I just need to pack this plugin along with Qt6Network and all set!