# How to use qt tls plugin in CMake

Tags: qt, cmake

I'm trying openssl on Windows with qt6.5. I've found that tls on 6.5 needs [tls plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73064050/trying-to-build-qt-6-3-1-and-dynamic-linked-with-openssl-3-0-5-on-windows). It works if I copy tls from qt dir to build dir. What's the proper way to do it with CMake?